# Ubuntu/Netgar WAX218: How to fix failing wifi connection to access point? (Activation of network connection failed)

Tags: linux, ubuntu, wireless-networking, netgear-router

After the wireless access point (Netgear WAX218 - AX3600 WiFi 6 Dual Band PoE+) and the Ubuntu (2022.10) system were plugged off for nearly three months, Ubuntu is no longer able to connect to the network. Instead it automatically connects to the access point's configuration wifi. Simply switching connection to the configured network triggers an error notification reading:

```
Connection failed 
Activation of network connection failed
```

**Here's what's strange:**
<s>The access point's wifi network is still working with all other devices on the network. It's only the Ubuntu box that has problems.</s> Connecting the Ubuntu box to another network, like a mobile hotspot for example, also works, hence it's not a malfunction of the wifi adapter, but something between the access point and Ubuntu.

The Ubuntu box was used to setup the access point's wifi network, which is most likely the reason why it automatically connects to the access point's configuration wifi.

Question now is, how to fix this without resetting the access point?
If you have any ideas, please share them.

Beside that, here's what's logged to syslog between two connection attempts:

```
Mar  7 18:27:28 i7 NetworkManager[1316]: <info>  [1678210048.3813] policy: auto-activating connection 'SchneckeRunRunRun' (e9e1cc7f-7381-42e8-895c-440a8e516035)
Mar  7 18:27:28 i7 NetworkManager[1316]: <info>  [1678210048.3817] device (wlp3s0): Activation: starting connection 'SchneckeRunRunRun' (e9e1cc7f-7381-42e8-895c-440a8e516035)
Mar  7 18:27:28 i7 NetworkManager[1316]: <info>  [1678210048.3818] device (wlp3s0): state change: disconnected -> prepare (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Mar  7 18:27:28 i7 NetworkManager[1316]: <info>  [1678210048.3820] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTING
Mar  7 18:27:28 i7 NetworkManager[1316]: <info>  [1678210048.3823] device (wlp3s0): state change: prepare -> config (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Mar  7 18:27:28 i7 NetworkManager[1316]: <info>  [1678210048.3825] device (wlp3s0): Activation: (wifi) access point 'SchneckeRunRunRun' has security, but secrets are required.
Mar  7 18:27:28 i7 NetworkManager[1316]: <info>  [1678210048.3825] device (wlp3s0): state change: config -> need-auth (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Mar  7 18:27:28 i7 NetworkManager[1316]: <info>  [1678210048.3832] device (wlp3s0): state change: need-auth -> prepare (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Mar  7 18:27:28 i7 NetworkManager[1316]: <info>  [1678210048.3835] device (wlp3s0): state change: prepare -> config (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Mar  7 18:27:28 i7 NetworkManager[1316]: <info>  [1678210048.3837] device (wlp3s0): Activation: (wifi) connection 'SchneckeRunRunRun' has security, and secrets exist.  No new secrets needed.
Mar  7 18:27:28 i7 NetworkManager[1316]: <info>  [1678210048.3837] Config: added 'ssid' value 'SchneckeRunRunRun'
Mar  7 18:27:28 i7 NetworkManager[1316]: <info>  [1678210048.3837] Config: added 'scan_ssid' value '1'
Mar  7 18:27:28 i7 NetworkManager[1316]: <info>  [1678210048.3837] Config: added 'bgscan' value 'simple:30:-70:86400'
Mar  7 18:27:28 i7 NetworkManager[1316]: <info>  [1678210048.3837] Config: added 'key_mgmt' value 'WPA-PSK WPA-PSK-SHA256 FT-PSK SAE FT-SAE'
Mar  7 18:27:28 i7 NetworkManager[1316]: <info>  [1678210048.3838] Config: added 'auth_alg' value 'OPEN'
Mar  7 18:27:28 i7 NetworkManager[1316]: <info>  [1678210048.3838] Config: added 'psk' value '<hidden>'
Mar  7 18:27:28 i7 wpa_supplicant[1215]: wlp3s0: Reject scan trigger since one is already pending
Mar  7 18:27:28 i7 wpa_supplicant[1215]: wlp3s0: Failed to initiate AP scan
Mar  7 18:27:28 i7 wpa_supplicant[1215]: wlp3s0: CTRL-EVENT-REGDOM-CHANGE init=BEACON_HINT type=UNKNOWN
Mar  7 18:27:29 i7 wpa_supplicant[1215]: wlp3s0: CTRL-EVENT-REGDOM-CHANGE init=BEACON_HINT type=UNKNOWN
Mar  7 18:27:29 i7 wpa_supplicant[1215]: wlp3s0: Reject scan trigger since one is already pending
Mar  7 18:27:29 i7 wpa_supplicant[1215]: wlp3s0: Failed to initiate AP scan
Mar  7 18:27:30 i7 wpa_supplicant[1215]: wlp3s0: Reject scan trigger since one is already pending
Mar  7 18:27:30 i7 wpa_supplicant[1215]: wlp3s0: Failed to initiate AP scan
Mar  7 18:27:31 i7 wpa_supplicant[1215]: wlp3s0: Reject scan trigger since one is already pending
Mar  7 18:27:31 i7 wpa_supplicant[1215]: wlp3s0: Failed to initiate AP scan
Mar  7 18:27:32 i7 NetworkManager[1316]: <info>  [1678210052.9010] device (wlp3s0): supplicant interface state: disconnected -> scanning
Mar  7 18:27:36 i7 systemd[1]: NetworkManager-wait-online.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Mar  7 18:27:36 i7 systemd[1]: NetworkManager-wait-online.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Mar  7 18:27:36 i7 systemd[1]: Failed to start Network Manager Wait Online.
Mar  7 18:27:36 i7 systemd[1]: Reached target Network is Online.
Mar  7 18:27:36 i7 systemd[1]: Started Download data for packages that failed at package install time.
Mar  7 18:27:36 i7 systemd[1]: Started Check to see whether there is a new version of Ubuntu available.
Mar  7 18:27:36 i7 systemd[1]: Reached target Timer Units.
Mar  7 18:27:36 i7 systemd[1]: Started Make remote CUPS printers available locally.
Mar  7 18:27:36 i7 systemd[1]: Starting Tool to automatically collect and submit kernel crash signatures...
Mar  7 18:27:36 i7 systemd[1]: Starting Samba NMB Daemon...
Mar  7 18:27:36 i7 systemd[1]: Ubuntu Pro Background Auto Attach was skipped because all trigger condition checks failed.
Mar  7 18:27:36 i7 systemd[1]: Starting LSB: VirtualBox Linux kernel module...
Mar  7 18:27:36 i7 systemd[1]: Started crash report submission.
Mar  7 18:27:36 i7 systemd[1]: kerneloops.service: Found left-over process 3417 (kerneloops) in control group while starting unit. Ignoring.
Mar  7 18:27:36 i7 systemd[1]: This usually indicates unclean termination of a previous run, or service implementation deficiencies.
Mar  7 18:27:36 i7 virtualbox[3413]:  * Loading VirtualBox kernel modules...
Mar  7 18:27:36 i7 systemd[1]: Started Tool to automatically collect and submit kernel crash signatures.
Mar  7 18:27:36 i7 whoopsie[3414]: [18:27:36] Using lock path: /var/lock/whoopsie/lock
Mar  7 18:27:36 i7 systemd[1]: whoopsie.service: Deactivated successfully.
Mar  7 18:27:36 i7 kernel: [   65.369171] vboxdrv: Found 12 processor cores
Mar  7 18:27:36 i7 kernel: [   65.388377] vboxdrv: TSC mode is Invariant, tentative frequency 3695997552 Hz
Mar  7 18:27:36 i7 kernel: [   65.388379] vboxdrv: Successfully loaded version 6.1.38_Ubuntu r153438 (interface 0x00320000)
Mar  7 18:27:36 i7 kernel: [   65.394592] VBoxNetFlt: Successfully started.
Mar  7 18:27:36 i7 kernel: [   65.400005] VBoxNetAdp: Successfully started.
Mar  7 18:27:36 i7 virtualbox[3413]:    ...done.
Mar  7 18:27:36 i7 systemd[1]: Started LSB: VirtualBox Linux kernel module.
Mar  7 18:27:36 i7 wpa_supplicant[1215]: wlp3s0: SME: Trying to authenticate with 94:a6:7e:b1:96:70 (SSID='SchneckeRunRunRun' freq=5200 MHz)
Mar  7 18:27:36 i7 kernel: [   65.894005] wlp3s0: authenticate with 94:a6:7e:b1:96:70
Mar  7 18:27:37 i7 NetworkManager[1316]: <info>  [1678210057.3015] device (wlp3s0): supplicant interface state: scanning -> authenticating
Mar  7 18:27:37 i7 kernel: [   66.480131] wlp3s0: send auth to 94:a6:7e:b1:96:70 (try 1/3)
Mar  7 18:27:37 i7 kernel: [   66.584182] wlp3s0: send auth to 94:a6:7e:b1:96:70 (try 2/3)
Mar  7 18:27:37 i7 wpa_supplicant[1215]: wlp3s0: Trying to associate with 94:a6:7e:b1:96:70 (SSID='SchneckeRunRunRun' freq=5200 MHz)
Mar  7 18:27:37 i7 kernel: [   66.590531] wlp3s0: authenticated
Mar  7 18:27:37 i7 kernel: [   66.592112] wlp3s0: associate with 94:a6:7e:b1:96:70 (try 1/3)
Mar  7 18:27:37 i7 NetworkManager[1316]: <info>  [1678210057.4119] device (wlp3s0): supplicant interface state: authenticating -> associating
Mar  7 18:27:37 i7 wpa_supplicant[1215]: wlp3s0: Associated with 94:a6:7e:b1:96:70
Mar  7 18:27:37 i7 kernel: [   66.594787] wlp3s0: RX AssocResp from 94:a6:7e:b1:96:70 (capab=0x1511 status=0 aid=1)
Mar  7 18:27:37 i7 kernel: [   66.595154] wlp3s0: associated
Mar  7 18:27:37 i7 wpa_supplicant[1215]: wlp3s0: CTRL-EVENT-SUBNET-STATUS-UPDATE status=0
Mar  7 18:27:37 i7 wpa_supplicant[1215]: wlp3s0: CTRL-EVENT-REGDOM-CHANGE init=COUNTRY_IE type=COUNTRY alpha2=DE
Mar  7 18:27:37 i7 NetworkManager[1316]: <info>  [1678210057.4219] device (wlp3s0): supplicant interface state: associating -> 4way_handshake
Mar  7 18:27:37 i7 wpa_supplicant[1215]: wlp3s0: WPA: Key negotiation completed with 94:a6:7e:b1:96:70 [PTK=CCMP GTK=CCMP]
Mar  7 18:27:37 i7 wpa_supplicant[1215]: wlp3s0: CTRL-EVENT-CONNECTED - Connection to 94:a6:7e:b1:96:70 completed [id=0 id_str=]
Mar  7 18:27:37 i7 NetworkManager[1316]: <info>  [1678210057.4661] device (wlp3s0): supplicant interface state: 4way_handshake -> completed
Mar  7 18:27:37 i7 NetworkManager[1316]: <info>  [1678210057.4662] device (wlp3s0): Activation: (wifi) Stage 2 of 5 (Device Configure) successful. Connected to wireless network "SchneckeRunRunRun"
Mar  7 18:27:37 i7 NetworkManager[1316]: <info>  [1678210057.4665] device (wlp3s0): state change: config -> ip-config (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Mar  7 18:27:37 i7 kernel: [   66.644284] wlp3s0: Limiting TX power to 20 (23 - 3) dBm as advertised by 94:a6:7e:b1:96:70
Mar  7 18:27:37 i7 NetworkManager[1316]: <info>  [1678210057.4677] dhcp4 (wlp3s0): activation: beginning transaction (timeout in 45 seconds)
Mar  7 18:27:37 i7 avahi-daemon[1102]: Joining mDNS multicast group on interface wlp3s0.IPv6 with address fe80::ea14:7efa:2e9a:9b8f.
Mar  7 18:27:37 i7 avahi-daemon[1102]: New relevant interface wlp3s0.IPv6 for mDNS.
Mar  7 18:27:37 i7 avahi-daemon[1102]: Registering new address record for fe80::ea14:7efa:2e9a:9b8f on wlp3s0.*.
Mar  7 18:27:37 i7 wpa_supplicant[1215]: wlp3s0: CTRL-EVENT-SIGNAL-CHANGE above=0 signal=-73 noise=9999 txrate=780000
Mar  7 18:27:37 i7 systemd[1]: NetworkManager-dispatcher.service: Deactivated successfully.
Mar  7 18:27:38 i7 geoclue[1687]: Service not used for 60 seconds. Shutting down..
Mar  7 18:27:38 i7 systemd[1]: geoclue.service: Deactivated successfully.
Mar  7 18:27:38 i7 systemd[1]: systemd-timedated.service: Deactivated successfully.
Mar  7 18:27:41 i7 dbus-daemon[1106]: [system] Activating via systemd: service name='org.freedesktop.nm_dispatcher' unit='dbus-org.freedesktop.nm-dispatcher.service' requested by ':1.17' (uid=0 pid=1316 comm="/usr/sbin/NetworkManager --no-daemon" label="unconfined")
Mar  7 18:27:41 i7 systemd[1]: Starting Network Manager Script Dispatcher Service...
Mar  7 18:27:41 i7 dbus-daemon[1106]: [system] Successfully activated service 'org.freedesktop.nm_dispatcher'
Mar  7 18:27:41 i7 systemd[1]: Started Network Manager Script Dispatcher Service.
Mar  7 18:27:48 i7 systemd[1936]: Started Application launched by gnome-session-binary.
Mar  7 18:27:48 i7 systemd[1936]: Started Application launched by gnome-session-binary.
Mar  7 18:27:50 i7 gnome-shell[2154]: JS WARNING: [resource:///org/gnome/gjs/modules/core/overrides/Gio.js 287]: Too many arguments to method Gio.AsyncInitable.init_async: expected 3, got 4
Mar  7 18:27:50 i7 ubuntu-appindicators@ubuntu.com[2154]: unable to update icon for software-update-available
Mar  7 18:27:51 i7 systemd[1]: NetworkManager-dispatcher.service: Deactivated successfully.
Mar  7 18:27:58 i7 snap-store[2390]: Failed to find refreshable snaps: status-code=500 kind=(null) message=cannot list updates: persistent network error: Post "https://api.snapcraft.io/v2/snaps/refresh": dial tcp: lookup api.snapcraft.io: Temporary failure in name resolution
Mar  7 18:28:00 i7 dbus-daemon[1949]: [session uid=1000 pid=1949] Activating via systemd: service name='org.freedesktop.Tracker3.Miner.Extract' unit='tracker-extract-3.service' requested by ':1.10' (uid=1000 pid=1969 comm="/usr/libexec/tracker-miner-fs-3" label="unconfined")
Mar  7 18:28:00 i7 systemd[1936]: Starting Tracker metadata extractor...
Mar  7 18:28:00 i7 dbus-daemon[1949]: [session uid=1000 pid=1949] Successfully activated service 'org.freedesktop.Tracker3.Miner.Extract'
Mar  7 18:28:00 i7 systemd[1936]: Started Tracker metadata extractor.
Mar  7 18:28:22 i7 NetworkManager[1316]: <info>  [1678210102.8241] device (wlp3s0): state change: ip-config -> failed (reason 'ip-config-unavailable', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Mar  7 18:28:22 i7 NetworkManager[1316]: <info>  [1678210102.8247] manager: NetworkManager state is now DISCONNECTED
Mar  7 18:28:22 i7 NetworkManager[1316]: <warn>  [1678210102.8254] device (wlp3s0): Activation: failed for connection 'SchneckeRunRunRun'
Mar  7 18:28:22 i7 NetworkManager[1316]: <info>  [1678210102.8258] device (wlp3s0): state change: failed -> disconnected (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Mar  7 18:28:22 i7 avahi-daemon[1102]: Withdrawing address record for fe80::ea14:7efa:2e9a:9b8f on wlp3s0.
Mar  7 18:28:22 i7 avahi-daemon[1102]: Leaving mDNS multicast group on interface wlp3s0.IPv6 with address fe80::ea14:7efa:2e9a:9b8f.
Mar  7 18:28:22 i7 avahi-daemon[1102]: Interface wlp3s0.IPv6 no longer relevant for mDNS.
Mar  7 18:28:22 i7 NetworkManager[1316]: <info>  [1678210102.8441] dhcp4 (wlp3s0): canceled DHCP transaction
Mar  7 18:28:22 i7 NetworkManager[1316]: <info>  [1678210102.8441] dhcp4 (wlp3s0): activation: beginning transaction (timeout in 45 seconds)
Mar  7 18:28:22 i7 NetworkManager[1316]: <info>  [1678210102.8441] dhcp4 (wlp3s0): state changed no lease
Mar  7 18:28:22 i7 dbus-daemon[1106]: [system] Activating via systemd: service name='org.freedesktop.nm_dispatcher' unit='dbus-org.freedesktop.nm-dispatcher.service' requested by ':1.17' (uid=0 pid=1316 comm="/usr/sbin/NetworkManager --no-daemon" label="unconfined")
Mar  7 18:28:22 i7 kernel: [  112.068339] wlp3s0: deauthenticating from 94:a6:7e:b1:96:70 by local choice (Reason: 3=DEAUTH_LEAVING)
Mar  7 18:28:22 i7 systemd[1]: Starting Network Manager Script Dispatcher Service...
Mar  7 18:28:22 i7 dbus-daemon[1106]: [system] Successfully activated service 'org.freedesktop.nm_dispatcher'
Mar  7 18:28:22 i7 systemd[1]: Started Network Manager Script Dispatcher Service.
Mar  7 18:28:23 i7 wpa_supplicant[1215]: wlp3s0: CTRL-EVENT-DISCONNECTED bssid=94:a6:7e:b1:96:70 reason=3 locally_generated=1
Mar  7 18:28:23 i7 wpa_supplicant[1215]: wlp3s0: CTRL-EVENT-DSCP-POLICY clear_all
Mar  7 18:28:23 i7 wpa_supplicant[1215]: wlp3s0: CTRL-EVENT-REGDOM-CHANGE init=CORE type=WORLD
Mar  7 18:28:23 i7 NetworkManager[1316]: <info>  [1678210103.0545] device (wlp3s0): supplicant interface state: completed -> disconnected
```

Your help is very much appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: The first thing to try is always forget/delete the connection and connect again. If any error please [edit] and update the question.

Comment: Try `rmmod wl` and `modprobe wl`. Also [this advice](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=235916).